# add class to item depending on select option

Tags: jquery, onchange, addclass

I am trying to add a class to a `<li>` when an option is selected from a drop down menu. 
Here is my simplified html:

```
<li id="customize-control-navbar_position" class="customize-control customize-control-select">      
<label>
<span class="customize-control-title">NavBar Positioning</span>

<select data-customize-setting-link="navbar_position">
    <option value="none">None</option>
    <option value="top">Top</option>
    <option value="under-header">After Header Section</option>
    <option value="hidden" selected='selected'>Hidden</option>          
</select>
</label>
</li>

<li id="customize-control-navbar_height" class="customize-control customize-control-slider">
<label>
<span class="customize-control-title">NavBar Height</span>

    <input type="text" class="kirki-slider" id="input_navbar_height" disabled value="130" data-customize-setting-link="navbar_height"/>

</label>
</li>
```

Here is my JS

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var navbar_pos_val = $('#customize-control-navbar_position select').val();
    $("#customize-control-navbar_position").change(function() {
    if (navbar_pos_val == 'hidden') {
        $('#customize-control-navbar_height').addClass('disabled');
    }
    });

});
```

I'm trying to add the class "disabled" to the `<li>` `#customize-control-navbar_height` when "hidden" is selected. Currently there is some odd behavior with this code, sometimes it works when any option is selected, other times it doesn't work at all. I'm wondering if anyone can see any obvious issues with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix it:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("#customize-control-navbar_position").change(function() {
      var navbar_pos_val = $('#customize-control-navbar_position select').val();
      if (navbar_pos_val == 'hidden') {
        $('#customize-control-navbar_height').addClass('disabled');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this, just out of interest, how do I remove class if a different option is selected after?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't update the value of navbar_pos_val  every time there's a change on the seleceted time. Try like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{

    $("#customize-control-navbar_position").change(function() 
    {
         var navbar_pos_val = $('#customize-control-navbar_position select').val();
        if (navbar_pos_val == 'hidden')
        {
          $('#customize-control-navbar_height').addClass('disabled');
         }
    });

});
```